# How to split paragraph by <br> using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a source file in HTML where there are `<br>` tags inside of paragraphs (or other block tags). I need to split the parent block tag by this break into multiple tags of the same type. For example,

```
<p>
First block of text
<br>
Second block of text
</p>
```

should be splet into:

```
<p>
First block of text
</p>
<p>
Second block of text
</p>
```

Simple `replaceWith("</p><p>")` doesn't work as this text is escaped.

There is a corner case however, when the `<br>` is inside of another tag (e.g. `<span></span>`):

```
<p>
First block of text
<span>
<br>
</span>
Second block of text
</p>
```

I'm not sure if that is a valid HTML, but if it is (is it?), I still need to split the paragtaph into something that is a valid HTML.

What is the best and idiomatic way to do that?

Comment: The 3rd example is not valid.

Comment: @HKboy, does that mean that I can count on that `soup.findAll("br")[0].parent` is always a block tag (`<p>` in my case)?

Comment: Yes, I think it is easier to do than replacing text.

Comment: @HKboy, I think it is valid HTML.  e.g.
"<p>A<i>B<br>C</i>D</p>"